# Independent of two Random Variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability

Let $X, Y$ and $Z$ are all binary random variables, and $Y = X + Z \mod 2.$

$X$ and $Z$ are independent.

a) Suppose $X$ and $Z$ are both uniformly distributed. Are $X$ and $Y$ independent? Why?  (Prove or disprove it.)

b) Suppose $X$ and $Z$ are not uniformly distributed. Are $X$ and $Y$ independent? Why? (Prove or disprove it.)

What I have tried for part (a) since $X$ and $Z$ are independent and uniformly distributed over $\{0,1\}$ then 
$P(X=0) =P(X=0,Z=0) + P(X=1,Z=1) = .5\times .5 +.5\times .5 = .5$ then $p(Y=1) =.5$ in case (a) $Y$ also is uniformly distributed. 
$P(X=0,Y=0) = P(X=0) P(Y=0|X=0)$  how can I complete the proof for part (a) I don't know how to calculate $P(Y=0|X=0)$ ?

How about part (b) ?

Answer (score 1):

Use the formula for conditional probability:
$$P(Y=0 \mid X=0) = \frac{P(Y=0 \text{ and } X=0)}{P(X=0)}$$
and re-write the numerator as a probability involving only $X$ and $Z$. Then use independence of $X$ and $Z$.

Comment: How can I write P(y=0,x=0) as a probability involves x and z only ?

Comment: $Y=0$ and $X=0$ if and and only if $X=0$ and $Z=...$?

Comment: So p(y=0|x=0) = P(x=0,z=0) ? so in case (a) x and y are not independent ?

Comment: No, $P(Y=0 \text{ and } X=0)=P(X=0 \text{ and } Z=0)$ but you forgot there is also a denominator of $P(X=0)$ in the conditional probability formula for $P(Y=0 \mid X=0)$.

Comment: How about part (b) ?

Comment: Try repeating the calculation for part (a), but with $P(X=0)=P(Z=0)=p$ and $P(X=1)=P(Z=1)=1-p$. Does it work?